# Раздувает ArrayList по непонятной мне причине android

Tags: android, циклы, kotlin

Беру через апи с сервера список вопросов, и при наличии ответов. Задача стоит простая как мне кажется - просеять список вопросов которые будут показаны пользователю посредством анализа списка ответов и списка вопросов. У элемента списка вопросов есть свой идентификатор который при ответе отправляется в массив ответов. Я получаю данные и просеиваю их, но по итогу массив просеянных значений вопросов превосходит изначальный неотфильтрованный в десятки тысяч раз. К примеру массив вопросов неотфильтрованных - 212, а отфильтрованных - около 30к. Вот как я делаю это:

```
val answers: ArrayList<AnswerModel> = response.body()!!.applicant_answers!!
var qType1: ArrayList<QuestionModel>? = ArrayList()
if (!response.body()!!.questions.isNullOrEmpty()) {
    qType1 = response.body()!!.questions!!
}
for (i in 0 until answers.size) {
   for (j in 0 until qType1!!.size) {
     if (qType1[j].id!! != answers[i].question) {
         questionType1.add(qType1[j])
     }
    }
}
```

Вероятнее всего где-то ошибся. Думал при достижении размера массива вопросов делать break но это не помогло. Не могу понять где ошибка. Либо у меня все правильно сделано, но в логи выводится ересь какая-то.

### UPD

```
for (i in 0 until answers.size) {
    for (j in 0 until qType1!!.size) {
        if(qType1.elementAt(j).id != answers.elementAt(i).question){
           questionType1.add(qType1.elementAt(j))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: В коде просеивание наоборот - каждый вопрос добавляется столько раз, сколько существует не равных ему идентификаторов.

Comment: В качестве костыля можно пока использовать не список, а сет. А так нужно править. Итерировать несколько раз по каждому вопросу - не дело.

Comment: @Эникейщик, тут вопрос не в костыле а в рабочем решении ,я вот пробовал сделать, но что-то не особо получилось :(

Comment: Так оно будет рабочее - в сете нет дубликатов. Только с кучей ненужных итераций.

Comment: я так понимаю вместо arraylist юзать hashset? но разве так будет нормально работать, или вы вместо списка ответов сет предлагаете использовать?

Comment: @Эникейщик, обновил код в вопросе, это то что вы имели в виду, или я не так понял?

Comment: Эта задача делается не так - нужно в циклах удалять из полученного списка ненужное, а потом добавить что останется в основной (если я конечно правильно понял смысл затеи)

Comment: @woesss, но ведь при удалении элементов цикл слетит из-за конфликта индексов, можете оформить как ответ то что по вашему мнению будет правильным, потому что у меня иссякли все идеи уже?)

Comment: Я в котлине не шарю, как там списки итерируются понятия не имею. Чтобы индексы не слетали можно, например, использовать обратный цикл (с конца в начало)

Comment: можно на java мне хоть принцип понять что да как, а то не могу понять суть решения)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Полагаю требуется что-то вроде такого

```
val answers: ArrayList<AnswerModel> = ...
val questions: ArrayList<QuestionModel> = ...

val filteredQuestions = questions.filter { question ->
    answers.none { answer -> answer.question == question.id }
}

questionType1.addAll(filteredQuestions)
```

Более оптимальный по скорости вариант, если данных много

```
val notNeededQuestions = answers.asSequence().map { it.question }.toHashSet()
val filteredQuestions = questions.filter { question ->
     question.id !in notNeededQuestions
}
questionType1.addAll(filteredQuestions)
```

Comment: а вы можете прокомментировать ваш второй вариант, потому что я сейчас пытаюсь вникнуть в ваше решение, и не очень понятно?)

Comment: ну если я правильно понял, то вам нужны такие `QuestionModel` из `qType1`, `id` которых нет в `answers`, так? Так вот тогда мы формируем множество `notNeededQuestions ` которое содержит `questions id`, которые нам не нужны. И тогда отсеиваем все `questions` по принципу: берём тот `question`, `id` которого не было в `notNeededQuestions` (и соответственно в `answers`), а поиск по HashSet имеет в среднем константное время

Comment: Первое решение имеет такую же логику, но там для каждого `question` производится линейный поиск по `answers`, что имеет сложность O(n^2) в отличии от второго варианта, который в среднем будет работать за O(n), (хотя худший вариант может быть и за O(n^2))

Comment: понимаете в чем сейчас загвоздка - оба эти ответа дают разные решения, и я немного в замешательстве))

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko даже сейчас проверил, выдаёт одинаковый результат на обоих алгоритмах. А как у вас результат отличается? Вы не забыли во втором примере сделать `questionType1.addAll(filteredQuestions)`?

Comment: обновил вопрос, добавил получаемые результаты

Comment: ваш вариант практически идеален по скорости, но вот появился вопрос - как регулировать кол-во отфильтрованных результатов, например я хочу взять последние 20 отвеченных вопросов и прилепить к общему массиву, я вот этого никак не могу понять, где оно у вас регулируется)

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko Я не понимаю, что вы хотите. Что такое общий массив и где хранятся отвеченные вопросы?  в questionType1, в answer? называйте переменные нормальными именами. Насколько я понял, в моём filteredQuestions должны быть не отвеченные вопросы, так или нет? В любом случае вопрос не раскрыт, я ориентировался лишь на приведённый пример кода. И дальше я навряд ли смогу помочь. Если вам нужно взять 20 последних элементов от массива, то для этого есть функция `takeLast()`. `val last20 = list.takeLast(20)`

Comment: все я понял)) спасибо большое, за ответ :)

Answer (score 3):

Эта задача решается так: сначала удаляется из полученного списка ненужное, потом оставшееся добавляется в основной. Пример на java:

```
ArrayList<AnswerModel> answers = ...;
ArrayList<QuestionModel> qType1 = ...;

for (int i = qType1.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    for (AnswerModel answer : answers) {
        if (qType1.get(i).id == answer.question) {
            qType1.remove(i);
            break;
        }
    }
}

questionType1.addAll(qType1);
```

Если список `qType1` должен использоваться в оригинале где-то ещё, то для задачи надо сделать копию.